# My proof that if $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$, then $A \subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm not sure if my proof is sound.

Here it is:

> Assume that $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$, so any subset C of A is also a subset of B. Therefore, any element in C is also an element of A, and by the same reasoning is an element of B. Thus $A \subseteq B$, as all the elements in A are proven to be elements in B.

I believe that I've covered that every single element in A must be an element in B, but for some reason I feel doubtful. Is my proof correct?

Comment: What does $P$ mean?

Comment: Don't bother with a set $C$. Just say, $$a\in A ~~\Rightarrow~~ \{a\}\in P(A) ~~\Rightarrow~~ \{a\}\in P(B) ~~\Rightarrow~~ a\in B.$$ @XianjinYang It means power set.

Comment: Power set i.e.P(A) is the set of all subsets of A.  Yeah, i like arctic tern's answer.  I felt your argument was right about I was a little worried about rigor.  What about the elements of a that *aren't* in C.  Well, they are in *another* subset of A obviously. but now we've gone down a syntactic mess and the whole thing can get tangled.

Comment: ... or I was thinking of inserting:  "Assume that P(A)⊆P(B),**any a in A must be an element of some some subset C of A.  And** so ... subset C of A is also a subset of B. Therefore, **a in C** ... is also an element of A, and by the same reasoning is an element of B."  It's just a *teensy* bit stronger (but not as strong as arctic tern's).

Answer (score 7):

Half-line proof, without using elements:

$A\in\mathcal P(A)$, hence $A\in\mathcal P(B)$, which means $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: This is by far the easier proof.

Comment: and by far the best.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can sort of do as you did and use the fact that $$x\in A\implies \{x\}\in P(A)\stackrel{\text{hypothesis}}{\implies} \{x\}\in P(B)\implies x\in B$$

But you can also directly observe that $$A\subseteq B\stackrel{\text{by def.}}{\iff} A\in P(B)$$ and use $A\in P(A)$ to conclude.

Comment: I'd start with the simpler version. There is no need to deal with elements of $A$.

Comment: @egreg It was somehow to address the poster's original attempt.

Comment: Well, the original attempt is flawed. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

"Assume that P(A)⊆P(B), so any subset C of A is also a subset of B." True.

"Therefore, any element in C is also an element of A," 
Here you are missing a quantifier. This is true for all C, but which C are you choosing? In order to prove $A\subseteq B$, you need to start with an arbitrary element of $A$ and show it is in $B$. You've started with an arbitrary element of an unspecified set $C$.

Here's a pretty easy proof. Since $P(A)\subseteq P(B)$ and $A\in P(A)$, that means $A\in P(B)$, so $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: ooh... slick...

Answer (score 1):

Yes the idea is right. I might phrase it differently thought, without the set C.

> Let $a\in A$, now $\{a\}\in P(A)\subseteq P(B)$, and thus $\{a\}\in P(B)$, and hence $a\in B$.